# Excel Macro to validate CSV field format

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to read a CSV file where there is a field called systemdate available and the format of that field is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0".

So while reading the CSV I need to check the field value to see if it is in the above mentioned format or not.

For example, if the field value is 2017-04-18 12:56:32.0 then it's correct. If not then it should throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

use NumberFormat to determine it.
If your range is in cell A1 to check it then use:
You can change that range per your needs.

```
Sub check_Format()
Dim chk As String

chk = NUMFormat(Range("A1"))

If chk = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0" Then
    MsgBox "Format OK"
Else
    MsgBox "Format Not OK"
End If
End Sub

Function NUMFormat(r As Range)
  NUMFormat = r.NumberFormat
End Function
```

Former function you can use to check format directly in the cell. For example in B1 write:

```
=NUMFormat(A1)
```

Comment: Hi it's not working.. could you elaborate little bit pls.

Comment: With .NumberFormat you can get string of formatted cell. Compare that result with a desired string "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0" to see does they match.

Comment: Hi OES , I am new to macro. Honestly very less knowledge on macro. Could you please help me to guide me step by step what to write where .

Comment: Insert module, copy above function NUMFormat and if your data is in cell A1 then use function in some other cell (like B1) =NUMFormat(A1) to get text string of formatted cell. If this is what you want to compare we can move further.

Comment: Hi .. I added a new module and pasted the function. My data is in C1 . Now how to call the function NUMFormat in my main module.?

Comment: You can call it. For example:    Dim M as string;    M = NUMFormat(Range("E14"));    MsgBox NM

Comment: Thanks OES.. but where to add the if condition and in the function no where we are checking the Format ?  Pls help me to write the macro.

Comment: Hi there.. still I am struggling ...Anyone there to help me .

Comment: I've edited mine above post. Now you have two routines: SUB where you can put your code and Function to determine what is the format of the cell. If you put some date in A1 and format it as you like then above SUB should return OK or NOT OK depending doe it match.

Comment: Thanks OES.. it didn't work for me. I wrote a new function with help of others in a different way to check the format. Much appreciated your guidance .